# How do I give an object a fur material?

Tags: hair

I want to give the eye ( the part shaded in black) a fur material . I tried using the hair shader but it did not work.

[image: the part labelled black]

[image: i want to create this kind of fur]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the hair shader. It should be used together with particle system -> hair

then it could result in:

[image]

make sure to check children -> "interpolated" or "simple" so it will look better if you render. But still quite quick in the viewport.

longer hair:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked

Comment: you are welcome